# Chrome Extension - Event Pages/Message Passing is not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, messaging, content-script

I'm novice in Google Chrome Extension development and I'm running through an issue which is causing the **content script** not getting executed. Below is a detailed description of the issue.

I'm working an extension to read some DOM content from a web site per say **example.com** I've the following files and the respective code part of it.

**manifest**

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,

    "name" : "My First Chrome App",
    "description" : "My First Chrome App",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action" : {
        "default_title" : "Hello"
    },

    "permissions" : ["tabs"],

    "background" : {
        "scripts" : ["background.js"],
        "persistence" : false
    },

    "content_scripts":[
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://example.com/HomePage.aspx"
      ],
      "js": ["jquery_224.js", "content_script.js"]
    }]
}
```

**background.js**

My intention is to create a tab and surf to a page which is mentioned in the below script. And, it has to send a message to `content_script.js`

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: "http://example.com/HomePage.aspx" }, function(tab){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({authKey : "parse-dom"});
    setTimeout(function(){
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
    }, 2000);
  });
});.
```

**content_script.js**

Here I'm trying to read the `authKey` that I'm sending it from my `background.js`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,response){
    alert(request.authKey);
});
```

Unfortunately, I'm not getting the alert nor seeing any script errors. I have gone through the [Chrome Messaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) and followed the same

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
"content_scripts":[
{
    "run_at": "document_start",
```

More infos: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

or try putting a timeout on your background sendMessage

EDIT: I've also noticed on manifest.json you have an **HTTPS** match while you are creating a tab with an **HTTP** address

Comment: Didn't work. Time being, I've removed the `setTimeout` implementation. Btw, corrected my question related to **HTTP** and **HTTPS**

Comment: What about **chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {authKey : "parse-dom"})** or even putting it in a timeout **setTimeout( () => { chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {authKey : "parse-dom"}) }, 1000);**

Comment: Tried with this `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {authKey : "parse-dom"});`. Didn't work. Really don't need the `setTimeout` to be functional now in this case.

Comment: Hey, finally the `setTimeout` only helped me. I moved the `sendMessage()` inside the `setTimeout` and it started working. Thank you. Accepting your answer.